# Plotting Multiple Drawdowns in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to plot multiple drawdowns on the same plot. I know I can do it with lines, as in this: 
[image]

However, I'm really a fan of area charts. Is there a way I can plot these drawdowns without it being cumulative?

Currently getting this:
[image]

Which is clearly wrong. Does anyone have any tricks or workarounds for this?

Don't know if this makes a difference but here's my code:

```
Rolling_Max =MiscETFs_Data[['SPHB']].rolling(500, min_periods = 1).max()
Drawdown = MiscETFs_Data[['SPHB']].loc['2015':]/Rolling_Max.loc['2015':] - 1
Drawdown.plot(figsize = (20,10), kind = 'area')
plt.show()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Quantitative Finance.

Comment: Since your question was migrated here and you don't have a user here I'm only half expecting an actual answer, but here goes. How do you expect those area plots to work if they're _not_ cumulative? All those overlapping plots are guaranteed to hide one another if you start filling up the patches under (above) the plots. So I don't understand your requirements to begin with.